# Average Marginal Effects vs. Marginal Effects at the Mean

Tags: regression, econometrics, binary-data, logit, marginal-effect

Can the Logit regression produce different results for Marginal Effects at the Mean and Average Marginal Effects? If so, what does that mean?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/211277/7071).